# Displace z-axis with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to displace the z-axis to the middle of the x-axis with gnuplot?
I've found a great gnuplot script [here](http://matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=165642&ref=http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=3d%2520kurve%2520gnuplot&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDsQFjAB) which nearly fits my needs perfectly, except that the z-axis should be going up at the middle of the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default gnuplot draws a border and places the labels on this border.

Draw only a border at the bottom, i.e around (x,y)-Plane :

```
set border 1+2+3+4
```

or disable it completely:

set border 0

draw a zaxis through the x,y-origin, and place the ztics on the same:

```
set zzeroaxis lt -1
set ztics axis
```

same for x and y, if you like.